# Burning smell from AC vents after installing new thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I was installing a new thermostat ([ecobee3 lite Smart Thermostat, 2nd gen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06W56TBLN)) to my AC unit ([ARUF61D14AA](https://www.alpinehomeair.com/viewproduct.cfm?productid=453070945)). I opened my current thermostat and noticed that I don't have a C-wire (which is required for the ecobee3):

[image]

This wasn't much of an issue because the ecobee3 came with a power extended kit, though it required a little bit more setup. So the next thing I did was open up my AC unit and look at the wiring:

[image]

and the cables from the thermostat:

[image]

So to install the new thermostat, I disconnected the cables from the wire thermostat that went into the board and plugged them into the PEK (power extension kit). Then, I used the five wires coming out of the PEK and connected them to its corresponding terminals on the board.

The only wire was kind of tricky was the C-wire, since the outside AC unit needed a connection to the C-wire as well. So I used a wire nut for the PEK and outside AC unit wire to share a connection to the C-wire. This was my final setup:

[image]
[image]

I then wired the Ecobee thermostat exactly like the [instructions](https://www.ecobee.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/ecobee3lite_installation_guide.pdf) indicated for the PEK.

[image]

Then, I turned the A/C breaker on and went through the Ecobee initial setup (setting up wifi, preferences, etc..). I set the system to 'Cool' and lowered the temperature. I heard the AC turn on and after a few seconds we started smelling a burning smell from the vents. It could be smelled from both upstairs and downstairs (two-floor house). I immediately turned the A/C off from the breaker afraid that I would fry my A/C. **My question is what did I do wrong and what was the burning smell?** I checked all the wiring and board and nothing seemed burnt, also I double checked my wiring and nothing seems out of place. **Did I miss something in my setup or wiring?**

Some additional notes that might/might not be relevant:

- I then took out the new thermostat and put everything just like it was before (with the old thermostat), and everything seems to be working perfectly again. The A/C didn't have a burning smell or anything and is currently cooling perfectly.
- I had a suspicion that maybe when I turned the new thermostat to 'Cool' and lowered the temperature it tried to run the heating, which would explain the burning smell since I never run the heating (maybe only once a year). I don't know if this is the case since I shut off the A/C right after the smell, not sure if it was the heating. This turbine was spinning when I shut off the A/C:

[image]

- I have lots of pictures of before and after so I can provide more if needed.

Comment: With old T-stat in, run the heat. Same smell?

Comment: Can you post photos of the nameplate and wiring diagram on your indoor unit (air handler)?

Comment: I'll give it a try running the heat with the current T-stat. Couldn't find a wiring diagram, but here's the nameplate https://i.postimg.cc/brCnPDGh/IMG-4138.jpg

Comment: Can you clarify here... do you have an AC or a heat pump?  Does the air handler have a heater coil installed?  From your description, the smell sounds like a heater coil that hasn't been used in a while and the dust is burning off.  But, you keep saying AC... which is a very specific term.  The thermostat needs to know what kind of system it's managing ie. AC only, single-stage heat, two-stage heat, etc.